# Customize print footer on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, print, footer

When a page of my company internal wiki is printed I would like to add a brief confidentiality text on every page footer and a larger one at the end of the article.

There are 3 links at the end of each screen page: `Privacy policy`, `About` and `Disclaimers`. Neither the links nor their content appears on printed pages.

Is it a feature provided by the standard MediaWiki software?

If not, can I do it with some simple customization?

**EDIT**

I picked the answer that addresses only half of my problem because the other half cannot be addressed with Chrome/webkit because of [this very old bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17205).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation seems a bit inconsistent and is hard to answer without knowing what version you are using, but you should be able to a print only message to the Footer template [example here](http://teflpedia.com/MediaWiki_talk:Copyright)

Depending on what the message is you may be able to edit or add a System Message for printing. There is also a [coding option](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Messages_API#Additional_methods_of_printing_messages)

Comment: The teflpedia example answers half of my question, how to add a footer at the end of the printed document. Any idea about how to add a footer at the end of each printed page in a multi-page document?

Comment: This extension let's you set the Footer per page and /or use a global footer. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HeadersFooters  You can also edit the Print.css stylesheet with print only (as in my answer) to make sure certain seconds like copyright or disclaimers print

Answer (score 0):

You could edit a template (or more ideally copy, rename and then modify) in MediaWiki to achieve this. Templates are in the `skins` subfolder of your MediaWiki installation.

For example, you could edit the `VectorTemplate->execute()` function in `\skins\Vector\VectorTemplate.php` to include the HTML for your footer text if you were using the *Vector* template.